# Google Sheets script: how do I run a script only on the sheets whose names contain particular text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

(On Google Sheets)
I want to create a script that runs only on certain sheets in a spreadsheet. To do this I have created a script that creates an array of sheet names whose names (defined as a variable curSheetName) fit the following condition:

if(curSheetName == "CM:")

so currently the sheet name must equal "CM:", however I want it to be so that the script runs on all sheets that CONTAIN the text "CM:" in their title, but I can't find how to write that syntactically. In MySQL it is '%CM:%', in GSheet formulas you just use asterisks..

Here is my code:

```
// Get list of sheet names in an array format
function sheetnames() {
  // Define array
  var out = new Array()
  // Get sheets
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  // Work through each sheet one at a time
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
    // define the current sheet
    var curSheetName = sheets[i].getName();
    // determine if matches criteria
    if(curSheetName == "CM:") { //***************** NEED HELP HERE
      // put into array if matches criteria
      out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] );
//      RUN FUNCTION HERE
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated!
Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript `Array.indexOf()` method to achieve this.

---

#### Example:

```js
if (curSheetName.indexOf('CM:') !== -1) {
  ...
}
```

---

#### Documentation:

- [JavaScript `Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I substituted that line in and I get this error:
"TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object Sheet1."
Any thoughts?

Comment: @ChaPPer5, I've changed the answer to use `.indexOf()` rather than `.includes()`, looks like Google Apps Script doesn't have method `.includes()`, well, *included*...

Comment: Forgot to say thanks, so, thanks :D and I see what you did there